# Make stylesheets, with automatic dependency tracking

Tags: makefile, make

This is a revision of the code posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192738/standalone-gnu-makefile-tracking-import-statements-in-sass).

It's a Makefile that I want to use for compiling Sass files to CSS in web projects. For this, I typically have two folders `css` and `scss` in a theme's top level directory. The full Makefile has other duties (such as optimizing images), and needs to be run from that directory.

It uses embedded Guile code to generate dependency files for my Sass files.

### Usage

For those not familiar with Sass: Sass is a language for producing CSS. There are two read syntaxes for it, the original indentation-based “Sass” and one based on CSS’s syntax, “Scss”, which is used here. There are also several implementations of the compiler: Ruby, C, C wrapped in Javascript and Darcs. I’m using the bare-bones, pure C implementation `sassc`.

A simple usage is to compile a CSS file from an Scss file, e. g. `sassc style.scss > style.css`. Scss files may also include other Scss files, if the latter are prefixed with `_`. If Sass encounters a statement like `@import 'my-include';` it looks for a file `_my-include.scss`. Usually it looks in the current directory, but `sassc`, at least, allows to specify a list of directories, separated with `:`, with the `-I` option.

Typically, I have one or two top level Scss files without the `_` prefix, each corresponding to one CSS file of the same name. But I also have a rather deep tree of `@import`ed files. If *any* of the Scss files in that tree changes, I need to recompile the CSS.

### The generated dependency files

In the Makefile below, the embedded Scheme code produces the `.d` files. If I have an Scss file `_groucho.scss` that directly imports two other files `_harpo.scss` and `_chico.scss`, then the `.d` file produced for `_groucho.scss` would be:

```
_groucho.scss.d: _groucho.scss _harpo.scss.d _chico.scss.d
-include _harpo.scss.d
-include _chico.scss.d
```

If a Scss file, say `_chico.scss`, has no imports, the produced `.d` file would be:

```
_chico.scss.d: _chico.scss
```

This works insofar as it reduces the amount of files that are re-read on each file change. The [previous version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192738/standalone-gnu-makefile-tracking-import-statements-in-sass) re-read every file in the tree on a change of one of them. This, now, re-reads (and produces `.d` files) only for files upwards in the dependency graph. E. g., continuing the example above: Say, `_groucho.scss` is imported by the top level `marx-brothers.scss`; and further more `_harpo.scss` imports both `_gummo.scss` and `_zeppo.scss`. Then after changing `_gummo.scss` my code regenerates the dependency files `_gummo.scss.d`, `_harpo.scss.d`, `_groucho.scss.d` and `marx-brothers.scss.d`.

While this is an improvement, it still reads files unnecessarily and recreates `.d` files unnecessarily. Also, on a fresh run of `make` after a `make clean`, this recreates dependency files higher up in the hierarchy *several times* on the same run. While this is not a huge problem in practice, it's rather ugly.

```
SASS-EXTENSION := scss
SASS-DIR := scss
SASS-LIB-DIR := ~/share/bak.mdl/
CSS-DIR := css

SASS-CMD := sassc
SASS-EXTRA-ARGS :=

DEP-DIR-NAME := dependencies


WATCHMAKE := css # optimize-img
WATCHDIRS := $(SASS-DIR) $(SASS-LIB-DIR) # $(img-src-dir)


#    - Compiles scss files in $(sass-dir) to $(css-dir). $(sass-lib-dir)
#      may contain extra libraries not immediately part of the project for
#      inclusion. This tracks `@import` directives.  CAUTION: With the
#      current implementation this may break if any path involves spaces.
# [...]

###########################################################################
.SUFFIXES: # Delete the default suffixes
.DEFAULT_GOAL := development

.PHONY: development
development: css # optimize-img


# Courtesy of Toby Speight https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/75307/toby-speight
ifdef verbose
describe := @true
quiet :=
else
describe := @echo
quiet := @
endif

###########################################################################
# SASS

sass-srcs := $(wildcard $(SASS-DIR)/[^_]*.$(SASS-EXTENSION))
sass-tgts := $(patsubst $(SASS-DIR)/%.scss,$(CSS-DIR)/%.css,$(sass-srcs))

sass-src-subs := $(shell find $(SASS-DIR) -type f -name '_*.$(SASS-EXTENSION)')

sass-libs := $(shell find $(SASS-LIB-DIR) -type f -name '_*.$(SASS-EXTENSION)')

sass-dep-dir := $(SASS-DIR)/$(DEP-DIR-NAME)

# Getting dirnames and sorting them, making sure that local ones come
# before library ones.
sass-inc-dirs-local := $(sort $(foreach f,$(sass-src-subs),$(dir $f)))
sass-inc-dirs-lib := $(sort $(foreach f,$(sass-libs),$(dir $f)))
sass-inc-dirs := $(sass-inc-dirs-local) $(sass-inc-dirs-lib)

# Replace space separators with `:`
nullstring :=
space := $(nullstring) # end of line
sass-inc-path := $(subst $(space),:,$(sass-inc-dirs))

define sass-scheme-code
(use-modules (ice-9 format)
             (ice-9 regex)
             (ice-9 rdelim))


(define extension (gmk-expand "$$(SASS-EXTENSION)"))

(define dep-dir (gmk-expand "$$(SASS-DIR)/$$(DEP-DIR-NAME)"))

(define files
  (string-split (gmk-expand "$$(sass-src-subs) $$(sass-libs)") #\ ))


;; Lookup REF and return corresponding file path.
(define (find-inc-file ref)
  (let ((r (filter (lambda (x)
                     (string-match (format #f "_~a.~a$$" ref extension)
                                   x))
                   files)))
    (if (null? r)
        #f
        (car r))))


;; Return arguments of '@import' statements in FILE as a list.
(define (get-imports file)
  (define regex
    (make-regexp "^[[:blank:]]*@import[[:blank:]]+[\"']([-_[:alnum:]]+)[\"']"))

  (if (access? file R_OK)
      (call-with-input-file file
        (lambda (port)
          (let loop ((res '()))
            (let ((l (read-line port)))
              (if (eof-object? l)
                  (reverse res)
                  (let ((match (regexp-exec regex l)))
                    (if match
                        (loop (cons (match:substring match 1)
                                    res))
                        (loop res))))))))
      (throw 'file-error "Couldn't open file:" file)))


;; Return list of files that are imported by FILE.
(define (get-import-files file)
  (map find-inc-file (get-imports file)))


;; Return dependency for FILE as a string.
(define (make-dep-rule file dep-file)
  (let ((deps (map (lambda (x)
                     (string-append dep-dir "/" (basename x)))
                   (get-import-files file))))
    (call-with-output-string
     (lambda (port)
       (format port "~a: ~a~{ ~a.d~}" dep-file file deps)
       (format port "~{~&-include ~a.d~}~%" deps)))))


;; Create depencency file DEP-FILE for Sass FILE.
(define (create-dep file dep-file)
  (call-with-output-file dep-file
    (lambda (port)
      (display (make-dep-rule file dep-file) port))))
endef

# Load the guile code and make it available:
$(guile $(sass-scheme-code))

.PRECIOUS: $(sass-dep-dir)/%.d

vpath %.scss $(sass-inc-dirs)

$(sass-dep-dir)/%.scss.d: %.scss
    @echo Creating $@
    $(guile (create-dep "$<" "$@"))


$(CSS-DIR)/%.css: $(SASS-DIR)/%.scss $(sass-dep-dir)/%.scss.d
    $(describe) Compiling $@ from $<
    $(quiet)$(SASS-CMD) -I $(sass-inc-path) $(SASS-EXTRA-ARGS) $< > $@


css: $(sass-tgts) # css/style.css  #$(sass-tgts)) # $(CSS-DIR)/style.css

-include $(patsubst $(SASS-DIR)/%,$(sass-dep-dir)/%.d,$(sass-srcs)))

#-include $(sass-dep-dir)/style.scss.d


.PHONY: sass-depclean
sass-depclean:
    rm -f $(sass-dep-dir)/*.d

.PHONY: css-clean
css-clean:
    rm -f $(CSS-DIR)/*.css

.PHONY: clean
clean: sass-depclean css-clean


###########################################################################
# WATCH

.PHONY: watch

watch:
    @while true; do \
        make --no-print-directory $(WATCHMAKE); \
        inotifywait -qre close_write $(WATCHDIRS); \
    done
```

Comment: There's no `.DELETE_ON_ERROR:` target.  I recommend adding that, so that partial results from a failing command don't prevent it being re-run.